# Writing GPS coords to an SQL server in a loop

Tags: java, android, sql, gps, bufferedwriter

I am trying to send coordinates to a local SQL server I have set up. On the device, the user has a track recorded, which consists of tuples of lat/lon, else... They can click upload to send to server. In the code below, I am trying to write to the server with BufferedWriter in a loop, looping through each lat/lon tuple. However when I view what has actually been sent to the server, only a single entry has been sent, even though I loop X times. It appears I may be continuously overwriting BufferedWriter. Any help on how to send all data would be appreciated! I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOsZHuu8Qog&index=2&list=PLshdtb5UWjSppGmM3IdygV6RusjU3KjlZ

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(upload_track_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            ArrayList<TrackDataEntry> trackDataEntryArrayList = skiCompanionDatabase.getDataFromTrackID(trackID);

            Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "track data entries: " + trackDataEntryArrayList.size());

/////////PROBLEM HERE, keeps overwriting BufferedWriter... I think ///////////
            for (int i = 0; i < trackDataEntryArrayList.size(); i++) {
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("track_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackID), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("latitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackDataEntryArrayList.get(i).getLatitude()), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("longitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackDataEntryArrayList.get(i).getLongitude()), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("altitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackDataEntryArrayList.get(i).getAltitude()), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("speed", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackDataEntryArrayList.get(i).getSpeed()), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("timestamp", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(trackDataEntryArrayList.get(i).getTime()), "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                //bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();
            }


            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();

            trackUploadSuccess = true;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, that is because you try to send to server `POST` data with several (`trackDataEntryArrayList.size()`) `key-values` pairs with same keys: on every `for (int i = 0; i < trackDataEntryArrayList.size(); i++) { ...` step to `POST` data added same `"user_id"` (and others e.g. `"track_id"`, `"latitude"` etc.) key, and on server side can be extracted only one value for each unique key. To avoid that you should create request inside `for (int i = 0; i < trackDataEntryArrayList.size(); i++) {` loop - bad solution, or - better solution - use JSON array to send data to server, for example, like in [this](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/sending-json-data-to-server-using-async-thread/) article or like in answer for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38900957/6950238) question of [Breno Henrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987052/breno-henrique). And there is everything Ok with your tutorial, but it describes situation with only one "block" of `key-values`, without for loop.